# TableView insert data from list box javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a listBox which is populated with some data from my mysql database. I wish to add a selected item in a tableView from the listview. The problem is, when I click add button, the selected item gets added in the 1st cell. But when i select an another item then click add, it gets over written in the 1st cell. 
Here's my code.

```
Button Select= new Button("Select");
private TableView table = new TableView<>();
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
TableColumn<Map, String> NameCol = new TableColumn<>("NameCol");
TableColumn<Map, String> QuantityCol = new TableColumn<>("Quantity");
TableColumn<Map, String> PriceCol = new TableColumn<>("Price");
ObservableList <String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList (
        "0" , "1" , "2" , "3" , "4" ,
              "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" );

    table.getColumns().addAll(NameCol, QuantityCol, PriceCol);

    QuantityCol.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn (items));
    table.setItems(generateDataInMap());
    table.setEditable(true);
    table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.getColumns().setAll(NameCol, QuantityCol,PriceCol);

Select.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
               try {

                  table.setItems(generateDataInMap());
                  NameCol.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(Column1MapKey));
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(mainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
    });

private ObservableList<Map> generateDataInMap() {

     int count = 1;
     ObservableList<Map> allData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Map<String, String> dataRow = new HashMap<>();
        String value1 = nameView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        dataRow.put(Column1MapKey, value1);

        allData.add(dataRow);
        System.out.println(dataRow);
    return allData;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
```

I haven't written all the code, just the code block. Can someone please help me out. I'll really appreciate it :) :)

Comment: yes it I've tried it.. using that too replaces the data in the 1st cell. I need to add in the 2nd cell i.e the cell below it .. 
I am very new to javafx. It would be really nice if you could show me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for 4 days, i made this code...it works. :) 
If anyone need it, its written below.

```
public class mainMenu extends Application {
private TableView<foodTable> table = new TableView<foodTable>();
private final ObservableList<foodTable> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();   

Select.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
               try {
                 String FoodName = new String(nameView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());             
                 data.add(new foodTable(String.valueOf(rowid),FoodName,qtycb.getValue().toString(),String.valueOf(PriceAmtVal)));
                 rowid++;
                 System.out.println(data);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(mainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
    });
//Buttion code :

Select.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
               try {
                 String FoodName = new String(nameView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());             
                 data.add(new foodTable(String.valueOf(rowid),FoodName,qtycb.getValue().toString(),String.valueOf(PriceAmtVal)));
                 rowid++;
                 System.out.println(data);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(mainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
    });
public static class foodTable {

    private final SimpleStringProperty FoodName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty Quantity;
    private final SimpleStringProperty Price;

    private foodTable(String fName, String lName, String email,String Price) {

        this.FoodName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.Quantity = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        this.Price = new SimpleStringProperty(Price);
    }


    public String getFoodName() {
        return FoodName.get();
    }
    public void setFoodName(String fName) {
        FoodName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return Quantity.get();
    }
    public void setQuantity(String fName) {
        Quantity.set(fName);
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return Price.get();
    }
    public void setPrice(String fName) {
        Price.set(fName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler you are calling

```
table.setItems(...);
```

which sets the items shown in the table (i.e. replaces all those that are there with the ones you specify).

Use

```
table.getItems().addAll(...);
```

instead.

Comment: I replaced  `table.setItems(generateDataInMap());`  with `table.getItems().addAll(generateDataInMap());`
It is still over writing on the 1st cell :(

Comment: Can you please help me out :(